# How to format numbers using space as separater in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

For example, I can format using comma as separater:

```
(format "%,d"(BigInteger. "fffff" 16))
;=> 1,048,575
```

Is it possible to use space instead:

```
1 048 575 ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`cl-format`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html#clojure.pprint/cl-format) from `clojure.pprint`, which is an implementation of Common Lisp's rather extensive and very powerful [format](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm)

```
 user=> (cl-format nil "The answer is ~,,' :D" 123456789)
 "The answer is 123 456 789"
```

CL's `cl-format` has, like Clojure's regular `format`, several directives, here `D` for digits. The `:` modifier tells it to print commas between groups of digits, however, the `'` behind the second comma specifies to use a space as the comma-character to use.

Comment: Thank you. It's exciting to find a new powerful function in Clojure. I read some documentation. 1. The double commas looks a little bit weird. What does it mean? 2. Lowercase `d` will also work. Any difference?

Comment: And is it possible to add newline character at the end like \n? I want to print several numbers, each in a line.

Comment: The long answer would be really long, so the best short answer I have is to read a little through the linked CLHS documentation of `format`. I would recommend you read the basic options and then take a look at the examples. The [format section from "Practical Common Lisp" by Peter Seibel](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) can also serve as a nice introduction. It also has the answer on how to print multiple values from a list / sequence. Note you have to transform the CL code to Clojure. :-)

Comment: Thank you especially for the doc links. I'll read them and try my best to get a full understanding on the format package.

Comment: `format` does a good job, but there are some cases where nothing but `cl-format` will do a job easily.  For example, `(format "%a" nil) ==> "null"`, which is perverse, but makes sense given that `format` is a Java function.  `(cl-format nil "~a" nil) ==> "nil"`.  Sometimes `cl-format` directives look like line noise, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the best way, however, you can safely replace `,` with space. Anyway, after the number is formatted, it's just a string.

```
(clojure.string/replace (format "%,d" (BigInteger. "fffff" 16)) "," " ")
```

I tried to use `java.text.DecimalFormat`, and set the grouping separator by `setGroupingSeparator` method of `java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols`, but failed.

Comment: Thank you. I consider this as the last resort (yet it still works.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible using java.util.Formatter (which is what `clojure.core/format` ultimately uses). The code below, however, will produce the desired outcome:

```
(import 'java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
        'java.text.DecimalFormat
        'java.text.FieldPosition)

(defn format-bigint [i]
  (let [format (DecimalFormatSymbols.)
        out (StringBuffer.)]
    (.setGroupingSeparator format \space)
    (.format (DecimalFormat. ",###" format) i out (FieldPosition. java.text.NumberFormat/INTEGER_FIELD))
    (.toString out)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! You may also take a look at @schaueho's answer. That is: the `clojure.pprint/cl-format` function.